# c# entity framework - query and join multiple tables / entities

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, rest, entity-framework-core

Assuming I have the following tables (with similarly formed models, plus a few virtual props)

Tabel 1: "AgentCompany" (Simply links an agents ID to a company)
AgentCompanyId, AgentId, CompanyId

Table 2: "Company"
CompanyId, CountryId

Table 3: "Country"
CountryId, Name

The model for AgentCompany has a virtual property for "Company" and The model for "Company" also has a virtual "Country" property.

My query currently looks like

```cs
var res = (from ap in Repo.AgentCompany
           join p in Repo.Company on ap.CompanyId equals p.CompanyId
           join c in Repo.Country on ap.Country.Name equals c.Name
           where ap.AgentId == AgentFilter
           select new AgentCompany
           {
               Company = p
           });
```

This works, and i get all my data except that the Company (p) has its country as Null.
Im trying to fiugre out how to get this syntax to work so that since I can query the country as c shown above, i want p.Country = c, so in my AgentCompany object result, the Company property is the actual company, and the Company's virtual Country property points to a COuntry object.

Anyone know how I might achieve this? I have tried a few question searches and tried a few suggestions related to an inner join, or an "Include" method but I haven't been able to achieve what I want here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"with similarly formed models, plus a few virtual props"* - I guess you mean **navigation** properties (virtual has nothing to do here), but they are essential - with proper navigation properties you don't need all these joins and selects. The query should be simply `AgentCompany.Include(ac => ac.Company).ThenInclude(c => c.Country).Where(ac => ac.AgentId == AgentFilter)`

Comment: I'm not using method syntax

Comment: Sorry, didnt finish that comment on mobile - is there a way to do this in linq?